# Why do i get this exception when calling the google calendar event?

Tags: webforms

This code is export event to google calendar, it is working fine in local but after  upload the service in IIS server,i am getting this exception occurred.System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: 'The content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/XML; charset=utf-8).

```
public partial class UNGCCalendarEvent : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button 1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // WCFServiceClient client = new WCFServiceClient();
        using (UNGCCalenderSoapClient uNGC = new UNGCCalenderSoapClient())
        {
            uNGC.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 30);
            // EntityExtractionClient nlp = new EntityExtractionClient();
            uNGC.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 50, 0);
            string EventSummary = TextSumary.Text.ToString();
            string EventLocation = TextLocation.Text.ToString();
            string EventDescription = TextDescription.Text.ToString();
            string EventStartDateTime = TextStartDate.Text.ToString();
            string EventEndDateTime = TextEndDate.Text.ToString();
            string CustomCalenderName = TextCustomCalenderName.Text.ToString();
            string StartDatetimeZone = TextStartDatetimeZone.Text.ToString();
            string EndDatetimeZone = TextEndDatetimeZone.Text.ToString();
            string[] attendees = Textattendees.Text.Split(',');

            var a = new ArrayOfString { Textattendees.Text };

            string attachmentsfileUrl = TextattachmentsfileUrl.Text.ToString();
            //string s = new string(attendees);
            //string a = uNGC.UNGCCalenderService(EventSummary, EventLocation, EventDescription, Convert.ToDateTime(EventStartDateTime), Convert.ToDateTime(EventEndDateTime));

            string calendar = uNGC.ExportGoogleEvents(EventSummary, EventLocation, EventDescription, Convert.ToDateTime(EventStartDateTime), Convert.ToDateTime(EventEndDateTime), CustomCalenderName, StartDatetimeZone, EndDatetimeZone, attachmentsfileUrl, a);
            uNGC.Close();
        }




    }

    protected void BtnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UNGCCalenderSoapClient uNGC = new UNGCCalenderSoapClient();

       // UNGCCalender arrString = UNGCCalenderSoapClient.ArrayOfString();

        string EventID = TextEventID.Text.ToString();
        string EventSummary = TextSumary.Text.ToString();
        string EventLocation = TextLocation.Text.ToString();
        string EventDescription = TextDescription.Text.ToString();
        string EventStartDateTime = TextStartDate.Text.ToString();
        string EventEndDateTime = TextEndDate.Text.ToString();
        string CustomCalenderName = TextCustomCalenderName.Text.ToString();
        string StartDatetimeZone = TextStartDatetimeZone.Text.ToString();
        string EndDatetimeZone = TextEndDatetimeZone.Text.ToString();
        string[] attendees = Textattendees.Text.Split(',');

        string attachmentsfileUrl = TextattachmentsfileUrl.Text.ToString();

        //string s = new string(attendees);
        //string a = uNGC.UNGCCalenderService(EventSummary, EventLocation, EventDescription, Convert.ToDateTime(EventStartDateTime), Convert.ToDateTime(EventEndDateTime));
      //  string calendar = uNGC.UpdateGoogleEvents(EventID,EventSummary, EventLocation, EventDescription, Convert.ToDateTime(EventStartDateTime), Convert.ToDateTime(EventEndDateTime), CustomCalenderName, StartDatetimeZone, EndDatetimeZone, attachmentsfileUrl, arrString.AddRange(attendees));
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says that the WCF proxy received an *HTML* response instead of XML. Perhaps the server returned an authentication page instead of data. Which service did you call? Google Calendar doesn't have a SOAP API

Comment: Why did you use the ASP.NET MVC tag? ASP.NET MVC is a web app framework, it has no events or UI controls. This is Webforms code. The [TextBox.Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.8)  property is a string so `.ToString()` is meaningless.

Comment: I created one WebService and in that webservice i defined method which connects to Google Calender API 

and i am using the webpage to access the webservice

its working fine in debug mode. but when i host in IIS then it didnt work